# How to use properly multiprocessing with f(var, param1, param2, ...)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Let's consider a function f with one parameter to map (that varies) and several fix parameters:

```
f(var, param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

The `param i` are fixed values (like int, float, booleans, ...) and the `var` parameter is a list of objects.

**Current approach:**

```
p1 = 0
p2 = 200
var = [[Object(x, p1, p2), Object(y, p1, p2), Object(z, p1, p2 = test = True)] for x in range(5) for y in range(10) for z in range(25)]

for v in var:
    f(v, param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

Since the computation on one element of `var` does not depend of the others, I actually slice my list `var` and starts the program N times with N different slices, thus I got N programs running on the N core of my computer. 
It's kind of a manual way to do multiprocessing. However, it is not really convenient to keep track of what was done and what has still to be computed.

I would like to implement the multithreading / multiprocessing directly into the program.

Without fix parameter, I found this way that seems to works:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(processes = 16) # 16 cores.
p.map(f, var)
p.terminate()
```

With the small code above, I didn't use the same f function, it was for testing purpose only. How can I do that with my f function which has also fix parameters?

What is the best way? Thanks!

*Version of python: 3.6*

***EDIT:*** I would like also to have a tracking of the progression. Currently, my code is:

```
for i,v in enumerate(var):
    print ("{} / {}".format(i, len(var))
    f(v, param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

Could this be done as well with the multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, your question can be rewrite into:

How to easily map a function with several fixed parameters using multiprocessing?

something like `p.starmap(f, [(v, fix1, fix2, fix3) for v in dynamics])`?

I think you can wrap your `f` function.

For example:

```
def fixed_para_wrapper(dynamic):
    return f(dynamic, fix1, fix2, fix3)
```

Then you can use it like `p.map(fixed_para_wrapper, dynamics)`.

Comment: `p.map(f, [(v, fix1, fix2, fix3) for v in dynamics])` Damn I didn't thought about it... Thanks for pointing this out. It answers most of my question. Is the Pool.map the best way to do this? Are there other options in multiprocessing or multithreading libraries?

Comment: Um... You need to use `p.starmap(f, [(v, fix1, fix2, fix3) for v in dynamics])`. This is a popular way.

Comment: @Straw Ok I'll look into it. Is there a way to keep track of the progress with multiprocessing? (I would like to know how many elt of the list `dynamics` have been treated)

Comment: No, there isn't a easy way to do this. You should implement it by yourself.