# Useing global ftplib object with multiprocessing throws AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'

Tags: python, ftp, multiprocessing

I want send files by using Pool from multiprocessing, with openning only one FTP-connection. 
So, I've tried to do it with code below:

```
import multiprocessing
from ftplib import FTP 
import os
import glob

ftp = FTP()

def ftp_upload(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        ftp.storlines('STOR %s' % remote_path+filename, f)

def main():
    while True:
        if retry:
            file_list=sorted(glob.glob('*.txt'))
            pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
            pool.map(ftp_upload, file_list)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
        else:
            ftp.connect('host', port) 
            ftp.login('login','pass') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But this code executes with error, traceback is here:

```
   multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\parallel_FTP.py", line 20, in ftp_upload
    ftp.storlines('STOR %s' % remote_path+filename, f)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 529, in storlines
    self.voidcmd('TYPE A')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 277, in voidcmd
    self.putcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 199, in putcmd
    self.putline(line)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 194, in putline
    self.sock.sendall(line.encode(self.encoding))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
"""
```

- How can I pass ftp into ftp_upload() function?

Comment: [Edit] your Question an show the **full** Traceback. Beside this your `ftp = FTP(), ftp.connect, ftp.login` are **only** valid for the `main` process.  You have to pass `ftp` to `ftp_upload` in the `file_list` .

Comment: Done. thank you. Looks like ftp is global.. isnt it? How can I pass it to ftp_upload otherwise?

Comment: The Traceback confirms, `self.sock.sendall(...`, **no** `ftp.connect` for **this** process. `global` is useless for `multiprocessing`, mean, using a global object every processs has it's own copy of this global object. *How can I pass it...*: Read [multiprocessing-with-fvar-param1-param2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151486/how-to-use-properly-multiprocessing-with-fvar-param1-param2)

Comment: I feel, your attempt will fail anyway: Read rfc959 [Section: Reuse of the Data Connection:](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959.html)